# Binomial GLMM and model predictions. Is this method correct?

Tags: r, mixed-model, survival, binomial-distribution, glmm

I have a question concerning the statistical validity of methods. I have data about the survival probabilities of vegetative and reproductive structures of a plant along the flowering time. I am trying to model the survival probability of these structures between the different sexes (females, males), types (flowers and cladodes), and treatments (control and exclusion treatment).
The response variable was binomial, 1= alive, and 0= death. I did two methods to analyze this data, but I don't know if it is statistically acceptable.

First, I performed a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) with binomial error distribution with "probit" link function to estimate the survival probability of flowers between sexes, treatments and types. Using the next model:

`m.a <- glmmTMB(survival ~  sex * treatment *type +(1|ID),family=binomial(link="probit"),data=df)`

With this model, I used the same data for sex, treatments, and types to PREDICT the probabilities of each row of data used:

```
dPred <- data.frame(ID = df$ID, sex= df$sex, treatment = df$treatment, type = df$type)
```

then I used the new data to predict the probabilities of each row used in binomial model:

```
df.pred<- cbind(dPred, predicted = predict(m.a, type="response", newdata=dPred))
```

Then, I performed a Linear Mixed-Effects Model using these predicted data. I used the nlme package to fit the model:

```
model<- lme(predicted ~ sex * treatment *type, random= ~1|ID, data = df.pred)
```

I performed pairwise comparisons among the different independent variables using emmeans package.
My questions are:

Are these methods valid to infer the survival probabilities of these structures?
Is there a problem to use these new predicted data to fit this model and to make inferences about the differences among sexes, treatments, and types of structures?

Thank you
All the best